# Is it possible to use two (non-nested) for loops inside a dicitonary?

Tags: python

I have these two lists:

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'C']
b = [ 1 ,  2 ,  3 ]
```

And I want to merge them into a dictionary like this:

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```

I already tried doing stuff like:

```
{i: j for i in a for j in b}
dict(*a: *b)
```

Which outputs

```
{'A': 3, 'B': 3, 'C': 3}
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: That isn't "loops inside a dictionary" that is called a *dictionary comprehension*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'C']
b = [ 1 ,  2 ,  3 ]

print (dict(zip(a,b)))
```

Output:

```
{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```

Answer (score 4):

You should better use zip for this:

```
a = ['A', 'B', 'C']
b = [ 1 ,  2 ,  3 ]

{i:k for i,k in zip(a,b)}

#{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```

Comment: Much better in this particular case to simple do `dict(zip(a, b))`

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `enumerate`

```
d = {elem: b[i] for i, elem in enumerate(a)}
d

{'A': 1, 'B': 2, 'C': 3}
```